# how to get a variable of a python file from bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, variables, configuration

I have a python file, `conf.py` which is used to store configuration variables. `conf.py` is given below:

```
import os

step_number=100
```

I have a bash script `runner.sh` which tries to reach the variables from `conf.py`:

```
#! /bin/bash

#get step_number from conf file
step_number_=$(python ./conf.py step_number)
```

However, if I try to print the `step_number_` with `echo $step_number_`, it returns empty value. Can you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(command)` is replaced with the standard output of the command. So the Python script needs to print the variable so you can substitute it this way.

```
import os

step_number = 100
print(step_number)
```